# Stable matching solutions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The stable marriage problem is the problem of finding a stable matching between two equally sized sets of elements given an ordering of preferences for each element. A matching is a mapping from the elements of one set to the elements of the other set. A matching is stable whenever it is not the case that both:

**some given element A of the first matched set prefers some given element B of the second matched set over the element to which A is already matched**,

**and B also prefers A over the element to which B is already matched**

When the Elements of each group is 6 and if the list of each item in the element is given, how can i found how many Stable matching solutions are there.

Comment: please clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

Well, if there are only 6, then one possibility is just brute force. There are 6! possible matchings, just check them all and you have your solution.

Does not work (well, practically) though, when groups are bigger.

Comment: that's 720.. if i upload the lists would it help?